# Will an NSManagedObject ever turn into a fault while I have a strong reference to it?

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject

How can I know when to trust my NSManagedObject with stay around with its non managed variables. Surely a strong reference?

Comment: In general, it is a bad idea to keep a pointer to a managedObject as the object can be deleted and then using the pointer will cause a crash.  Better to fetch an object, use it, and then discard it.  If you NEED to keep a pointer to something then it should be an `NSManagedObjectID` or a `NSFetchedResultsController`.

Answer (score 1):

A managed object being a fault is unrelated to whether you have a strong reference to it. The comparison is sort of like saying, if I have a strong reference to an object, can its property values change? So yeah, it's possible for a managed object to re-fault regardless of what kind of reference(s) you have to it.

As a specific example, if you call `refreshObject:mergeChanges:` with your object as the first argument and with the second argument set to `NO`, you force the object to re-fault. But you can still have a strong reference to it.

But keep in mind that being a fault object has no relationship to whether it will "stay around", as you say. It still exists in memory. It hasn't been deallocated. You can even still use its property values.

Comment: My problem is I have a non-managed property that I don't want to vanish on me when I'm not expecting it. If I have VC.ManagedObject.extra then it seems to stay unfaulted and .extra stays, but when I have VC.ManagedObject.ChildObject.extra then ChildObject gets faulted out when i save the context and it loses the extra